# T_SQL query extreme value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

There is a table  T, with a random value in  id, How  with one select we can get extreme value of  id in input .
example :

```
T.id = 
12
34
76
89
1234
1254
6789
3456
```

For input we give  select  id=1254, as output we have to get two values  1234 and 6789

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You have no definition of the next or previous row without a column containing this information.  You should also tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do It in following:

**SAMPLE DATE**

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID INT)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (12),(34),(76),(89),(1234),(1254),(6789),(3456)
```

**INPUT**

```
DECLARE @var INT = 1234
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT Id, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn1
FROM #Test t
)
SELECT PrevId, NextId
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Id PrevId, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM #Test t1   
    ) previd ON cte.rn1 = previd.rn +1    
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Id NextId, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM #Test t1   
    ) nextid ON cte.rn1 = nextid.rn -1
WHERE cte.Id = @var
```

**OUTPUT**

```
PrevId  NextId
89      1254
```

**DEMO**

You can test It at <kbd>[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/162b5/1)</kbd>

Comment: But only we have to find right extreame value  - 6789. For input we give select id=1254, as output we have to get two values 1234 and 6789

Comment: But for 1245 It returning 1234 and 6789. What's wrong?

Comment: @Jack Strange, for `DECLARE @var INT = 1254` It Returning 1234 and 6789, I've tested It too. You can check It at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/162b5/1

Comment: You make pretty big assumption that `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` will return `data in the same unordered set as provided in sample data `. What if query optimizer tries to parallelize this process? Or just try with big enough data set  like (10k +) and add `OPTION (MAXDOP 4)`. And it may fail as house of cards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when id < 1254 then id end) as prev,
       min(case when id > 1254 then id end) as next
from t;
```

A similar approach produces two rows but is more efficient if you have indexes:

```
select 'prev', max(id)
from t
where id < 1254
union all
select 'next', min(id)
from t
where id > 1254;
```

EDIT:

I seem to have missed that the ids are out of order.  In that case, you need to assume that there is a column that specifies the ordering of the data.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no next or previous value.  You can handle this using window functions if you have a column for ordering:

```
with n as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by <ordering column goes here>) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select max(case when seqnum = theseqnum - 1 then id end) as prev_id,
       max(case when seqnum = theseqnum + 1 then id end) as next_id
from (select n.*,
             max(case when id = 1254 then seqnum end) as theseqnum
      from n
     ) n
where seqnum = theseqnum - 1 or seqnum = thesequm + 1;
```

Comment: It will fail with data like this: `(90),(11),(1254),(2),(5)`. This will work only if previous valus is lower and next value is higher than provided Id.

Comment: How about `OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`? It will return data in the same unordered set as provided in sample data or I'm wrong?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas . . . SQL tables are *unordered*.  In my experience, `over (order by (select null))` does not do a sort.  But, that doesn't mean that the results are in an order.  On a multi-threaded system, different threads could be returning data in many different orders.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which SQL Server version you're using. If it's 2012+ you can use [LAG()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [LEAD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) functions to achieve that quite fast:

**LAG:**

> Accesses data from a previous row in the same result set without the
>   use of a self-join in SQL Server 2012+. LAG provides access to a row
>   at a given physical offset that comes before the current row. Use this
>   analytic function in a SELECT statement to compare values in the
>   current row with values in a previous row.

**LEAD:**

> Accesses data from a subsequent row in the same result set without the
>   use of a self-join in SQL Server 2012+. LEAD provides access to a row
>   at a given physical offset that follows the current row. Use this
>   analytic function in a SELECT statement to compare values in the
>   current row with values in a following row.

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    ID INT
);

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES (12)
    , (34)
    , (76)
    , (89)
    , (1234)
    , (1254)
    , (6789)
    , (3456);


;WITH CTE (ID, Prev, Next, Extreme)
AS (
    SELECT ID
        , LAG(ID) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        , LEAD(ID) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        , MAX(ID) OVER ()
    FROM @Test
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE ID = 1234;
```

This query returns

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦═════════╗
║  ID  ║ Prev ║ Next ║ Extreme ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ 1234 ║   89 ║ 1254 ║    6789 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

As stated by lad2025, this and as well answered query will break if sql server optimizer decides to use parallelism.

Using `OPTION(MAXDOP 1)` hint might solve it. It tells sql server not to use parallelism.  Only correct way would be having column, that you could give stable order for your data set.

Comment: Same as first answer: You make pretty big assumption that `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` will return data in the same unordered set as provided in sample data . What if query optimizer tries to parallelize this process? Or just try with big enough data set like (10k +) and add `OPTION (MAXDOP 4)`. And it may fail as house of cards.

Comment: I never knew this. Thanks for the spot. Would using maxdop 1 help?

Comment: It prevents parallelism yes, it looks like it may help. But there is one catch without `ORDER BY` column you will never be 100% sure. Query optimizer is smart beast and inside can do what it wants and it may change between versions :)

Comment: I guess there's no other way to make it work unless OP's data set has some given order,which would guarantee correct result.

Comment: @lad2025 I've updates my answer with your comments. Thank you once more!